# How do I `eslint` my JavaScript when it depends on objects from previously loaded scripts?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gruntjs, eslint

I am wanting to add **eslint** to my WordPress plugin. But I keep getting an error message about an undefined name. At runtime, the name is defined by a previously loaded script within the browser. How can I get **eslint** to recognize that this particular name is okay?

Error from eslint::

```
/js/plugin.js
    13:12   error  'Cookies' is not defined                                    no-undef
```

My plugin's php loads the javascript files in the WordPress-way, using `wp_enqueue_script`. My plugin's javascript is dependent upon jquery and js-cookie, and js-cookie is dependent upon jquery. Therefore, Wordpress will ensure that the <script> for js-cookie comes before the <script> for my plugin.

plugin.php:

```php
    wp_enqueue_script( 'js-cookie', $path . 'inc/js.cookie.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'plugin-js', $path . 'js/plugin.min.js', array( 'jquery', 'js-cookie' ), '1.2.1', true );
```

My plugin's javascript uses the Cookies object to do various things.

plugin.js:

```js
(function($) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/wp-json/plugin-name/v1/method',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( data ) {
            process( data );
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
    function process(data) {
        if (Cookies.get('cookie-name'){
            ...
        }
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify `Cookies` as an externally-defined "global" in the file in which you use it. Add this to the beginning of `plugin.js`:

`/* global Cookies */`

You can also declare it in a configuration file, but this is less likely to be helpful to you given that it sounds like you are also defining `Cookies` (and thus it should *not* be declared as a pre-existing global in the file in which you define it).

See the [ESLint documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals) on specifying globals.

Comment: Using `/* global Cookies */` works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Excellent! Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

ESLint will only parse the file it is in, it doesn't any more context than that. You can ignore a rule by adding `// eslint-disable-line no-undef` after `if (Cookies.get('cookie-name') {`

Comment: I couldn't get this method to work. The error still showed up in the `eslint` output. Since my plugin.js is much longer than what I posted and referenced `Cookies` multiple times, declaring it as a global using `/* global Cookies */` at the top of my javascript file takes care of all occurrences.